# Verilog: === Operator Not Working

Tags: testing, verilog, iverilog

I have a wire:

```
wire module3Output;
```

In the end, I test the binary on the wire using:

```
initial
    begin
          if (module3Output === 1)
               #1 $display("PASS: module3Output=%b", module3Output);
          else
               #1 $display("FAIL: module3Output=%b", module3Output);
    end
```

Output:

```
FAIL: module3Output=1
```

Why is it failing when it clearly shows `module3Output=1`?

I can post full code if required.

Comment: Get rid of the `#1`s or move it before the `if` statement and what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem after a cold beer.

The delay needs to be put **before** the if-statement in order to give time for the data to pass into the wire `module3Output`. At time unit 0, `module3Output`'s value is 0 (by default), so the if-condition fails and the program goes into the else-condition. However, after a delay before the `$display` command, the data has reached `module3Output` and its value becomes 1, so it prints 1.

Fix'd Code:

```
initial
     begin
           #1 if (module3Output === 1)
                   $display("PASS: module3Output=%b", module3Output);
              else
                   $display("FAIL: module3Output=%b", module3Output);
     end
```